# iPhone/iPodTouch. What are my options for syncing movement to a soundtrack?

Tags: iphone, animation, audio

What are the best strategies for syncing music to object movement? The app I envision would have an underlying soundtrack with characters animating in time to the music. What I'm after is a strategy for having the soundtrack periodic send a message to an object, objects, triggering it to commence it's scripted movement.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

FMOD Ex should allow this sort of thing. It's not built-in, but it's relatively cheap.

Comment: I looked on the web site and don't see where it supports the iphone.

FMOD Ex has the largest range of supported hardware, including:

    * Windows (32bit and 64bit)
    * Macintosh (PPC and x86)
    * Linux (32bit and 64bit)
    * Sony PS2, PS3 and PSP
    * Microsoft Xbox and Xbox 360
    * Nintendo Gamecube and Wii
    * Solaris

Is an iphone release coming in the future?

Comment: I'm about to ship a product with FMOD Ex, so yes, it definitely supports iPhone.

Comment: David,
When you get some time I'd like to chat with you about your experience with FMOD Ex. I'm at douglass dot turner at gmail dot com or @dugla on twitter. Cheers.

Comment: FWIW, we didn't use sync points, but there is Sound::getSyncPointInfo which "Retrieves information on an embedded sync point. These points can be user generated or can come from a wav file with embedded markers."

Answer (score 0):

The point is writing the object movement code so that it can use external clock signal. You can for example write the movement update method so that it takes a time delta:

```
- (void) updateMovementBy: (double) seconds {…}
```

In each loop you’ll poll the soundtrack player for current playback time, compute time delta from the last iteration and update the model. But of course a lot depends on what exactly you want to do in response to the music.